# Add text instead of image in ASP navigation system

Tags: asp.net, navigation, content-management-system, rc

I'm currently working on a site that uses ASP and I think a 'custom' CMS.

I've got this navigation in a file called Rcp.Master -

```
<div id="nav">
    <Rcp:TopNavItem runat="server" Filter="default.aspx" HRef="" Alt="Home" Src="home.gif" Width="57" />
    <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem1" runat="server" Filter="about-us/*" HRef="about-us/" Alt="About Us" Src="about.gif" Width="79" />
    <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem2" runat="server" Filter="our-investments/*" HRef="our-investments/" Alt="Our Investments" Src="investments.gif" Width="123" />
    <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem3" runat="server" Filter="team/*" HRef="team/" Alt="Our Team" Src="team.gif" Width="78" />
    <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem4" runat="server" Filter="work/*" HRef="work/" Alt="Work with us" Src="work.gif" Width="108" />
    <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem5" runat="server" Filter="news/*" HRef="news/" Alt="News" Src="news.gif" Width="56" />
    <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem6" runat="server" Filter="comment/*" HRef="comment/" Alt="Comment" Src="comment.gif" Width="83" />
    <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem7" runat="server" Filter="contact-us.aspx" HRef="contact-us.aspx" Alt="Contact Us" Src="contact.gif" Width="68" />
</div>
```

At the moment as it shows it uses images for the navigation instead of actual text. I want to use 'actual text' so it's more like this -

```
<div id="nav">>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../about-us/index.html">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="../our-investments/index.html">Our investments</a></li>
    <li><a href="../team/index.html">The team</a></li>
    <li><a href="../work/index.html">Work with us</a></li>
    <li><a href="../news/index.html">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="../comment/index.html">Comment</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contact-us.aspx.html">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

How and where can I replace the src="" with just the text?

Any help will be greatly appreciated...

Stu

Here's the 'whole' rcp.master -

```
        <%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="Clear.Rcp.Www.RcpMaster, Clear.Rcp.Www" %>
        <%@ Register Src="~/Controls/TopNavItem.ascx" TagPrefix="Rcp" TagName="TopNavItem" %>

        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>R</title>
        <link href="<%=Root%>/css/rcp.css"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
        <script src="<%=Root%>/js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<%=Root%>/js/jquery.imghover-1.1rc.js" language="JavaScript"     type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="<%=Root%>/js/rcp.js" language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder runat="server" ID="PageHeader" />
    </head>

    <body><%=Root%>
    <div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><a href="/"><img src="<%=Root%>/i/logo.gif" alt="" /></a></div>
    <div id="nav">
        <Rcp:TopNavItem runat="server" Filter="default.aspx" HRef="" Alt="Home" Src="home.gif" Width="57" />
        <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem1" runat="server" Filter="about-us/*" HRef="about-us/" Alt="About Us" Src="about.gif" Width="79" />
        <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem2" runat="server" Filter="our-investments/*" HRef="our-investments/" Alt="Our Investments" Src="investments.gif" Width="123" />
        <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem3" runat="server" Filter="team/*" HRef="team/" Alt="Our Team" Src="team.gif" Width="78" />
        <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem4" runat="server" Filter="work/*" HRef="work/" Alt="Work with us" Src="work.gif" Width="108" />
        <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem5" runat="server" Filter="news/*" HRef="news/" Alt="News" Src="news.gif" Width="56" />
        <Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem6" runat="server" Filter="comment/*" HRef="comment/" Alt="Comment" Src="comment.gif" Width="83" />
<Rcp:TopNavItem ID="TopNavItem7" runat="server" Filter="contact-us.aspx" HRef="contact-us.aspx" Alt="Contact Us" Src="contact.gif" Width="68" />

</div>
</div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PageContent" runat="server" />
    <div id="footer">&copy; <a href="<%=Root%>/terms.aspx">Terms of use and disclaimer</a>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var _gaq = _gaq || [];
        _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-18033471-1']);
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

        (function() {
            var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
            ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
            var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
        })();

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Neil, to answer your question -

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Propeller.Web.NavItem, Propeller.Web" %>
<%if (!ShowOnState)
  {
    %><a href="<%=Root %>/<%=HRef %>"><img src="<%=Root%>/i/nav/<%=Src %>" alt="<%=Alt %>" class="hover" /></a><%
}
  else
  {      
%><a href="<%=Root %>/<%=HRef %>"><img src="<%=Root%>/i/nav/on/<%=Src %>" alt="<%=Alt %>" /></a><%
  }%>
```

As for if it's needed. This site is pretty Cray. Hard coded plus use of the CMS...Mental

Comment: It's a custom control, whats the code in ~/Controls/TopNavItem.ascx look like? Also is that control necessary?

Comment: added to the post Neil

Comment: can I just edit the Src in the master to the text then move <%=Src %> in between the ></a> ?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change the items to:

```
<Rcp:TopNavItem runat="server" Filter="default.aspx" HRef="" Alt="Home" Width="57">Text here</Rcp:TopNavItem>
```

If not, is there a bit at the top of the file that sets up the rcp namespace that might give a clue as to what system it is so you can google it?

Comment: Thanks Ben I get - http://cl.ly/image/3s1O4247413u - when I did that... Will add the whole rc.master file

Comment: mmm... i'm out of ideas then, you'll have to dig into the code a bit - google throwing nothing up, so guessing it's a proprietary cms, or a custom bit of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Propeller.Web.NavItem, Propeller.Web" %>
<%if (!ShowOnState)
  {
    %><a href="<%=Root %>/<%=HRef %>"><%=Alt %></a><%
}
  else
  {      
%><a href="<%=Root %>/<%=HRef %>"><%=Alt %></a><%
  }%>
```

Probably a bit hacky. But that should hopefully do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try inheriting from `TopNavItem` in your own server control. Then override the `OnPreRender` method and modify the `Controls` collection.

```
public class CustomNavItem : TopNavItem {
    protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnPreRender(e);

        // find ImageCtrl by examining Controls in debug session
        Controls.Remove(ImageCtrl);

        HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
        link.NavigateUrl = this.Href;
        link.ToolTip = this.Alt;

        Controls.Add(link);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the .master file delete replace any src="pageName.gif" with src="pageName".

In the TopNav file replace what's there with

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="Propeller.Web.NavItem, Propeller.Web" %>
  <%if (!ShowOnState)
    {
      %><a class="hover" href="<%=Root %>/<%=HRef %>"><%=Src %></a><%
    }
  else
    {      
      %><a href="<%=Root %>/<%=HRef %>"><%=Src %></a><%
    }%>
```